# I am trying to make a responsive text, but it's size is fixed no matter how big the screen is

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, nativescript

On the emulator the text looks OK, but on my phone it is to big for the line

```
<label text="just some regular text" class="text"> </label>
.text{
font-size: 20%;
}
```

Comment: {N} doesn't support % for font size, you may calculate the font size you want based on screen size and inject CSS on [application level](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_#addcss) at run time.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `%` value for the `font-size` property does not make the size proportional to the viewport size. It merely sizes the text relative to the parent element's font size.

For example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">This text is 50% of 32px = 16px;</div>
```

To make the font-size responsive there are a few options:

1. Use media queries to define font sizes for various breakpoints
2. Use viewport percentage units to make the font sizes scale with the viewport size

**1. Media Queries**

```css
.text {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">This font size is 16px when the viewport is between 320px and 599px, and 24px when the viewport is 600px or larger.</div>
```

**2. Viewport Percentage Units**

If you want the font size to be proportional to viewport size you can use any of the [viewport percentage units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths):

- `vw` - A percentage of the full viewport width
- `vh` - A percentage of the full viewport height
- `vmin` - A percentage of the viewport width or height, whichever is smaller
- `vmax` - A percentage of the viewport width or height, whichever is larger

For example:

```
  .text {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
```

would mean the `font-size` is 5% the width of the viewport. If the viewport is 1200px the font-size would be 60px; If the viewport is smaller, so 600px the font-size would be 30px.

There are some creative and interesting ways to use these viewport percentage units along with `calc()` to create responsive font sizes with a minimum size. For example:

```css
.text {
  font-size: calc(16px + 2vh);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">This text 16px + 2% of the viewport width.</div>
```

CSS Tricks has a [few great articles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/) on other ways to use the viewport percentage units.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. i tried to ad media queries but for some reason they are not in effect:

<label class="info" text="some text"></label>


@media screen and (min-width: 20) {
    .info{
        font-size: 30;
    }
}

Comment: you need to add units to the media query, like `@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {}`

Comment: If you look at the example above, those media queries will kick-in when the viewport is at 320px and 600px.

Comment: Also, you should add a unit to the font-size, like `30px`

Comment: can you look at my playground and tell me what i am doing wrong?

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qBJyv1

Comment: With your current code you have a single media query targeting viewports greater than 10px in width - which is really every viewport. When using media queries you will typically define a default size for the class, like `.text {font-size: 16px;}`, and then use a media query to increase the font-size when the viewport is larger than a certain size, like `@media screen and (min-width: 800px){.text{font-size: 30px;}}`.

Comment: See the example in the solution above where I have defined a default font-size, and a media query for larger viewports.

Comment: so why isn't my media query taking effect? why isn't the font-size getting bigger?

Comment: The code you currently have is not correct. Try to paste the code from the solution above (under the media query solution) into your playground. You need to define 2 font sizes - the default font size, with `.text {font-size: 16px;}`, and then a larger font size for larger viewports with `@media screen and (min-width: 800px){.text{font-size: 30px;}}`

Comment: i did it, but now it's just get the default. the media query is not in effect at all

Comment: Have you made your viewport larger than the `min-width` defined in the media query?

Comment: i put it for any view port larger than 1px, so i guess it is larger

Comment: Yes, I don't think you're following the solution above. A media query of `min-width: 10px` will target the viewport when it's larger than 10px. In that case your default size would show when the viewport is 0-10px in width, and your font-size in the media query would show when the viewport is greater than 10px. You probably need to set the media query to be at least 600px.

Comment: i don't get it. so my media query should target my device. why do i see the default?

Comment: You'll need to go brush up on media queries to understand what they do and how they're used I think. The media query says this - apply this CSS when the conditions of the media query are met. If the media query is `min-width: 600px`, then the CSS in the media query will be applied when the viewport is greater than 600px in width.

Comment: In order to see the style change from a media query, you need to resize your browser (or use the dev tools device mode) to change the viewport size so the CSS within the media query is applied and removed.

Comment: so when my media query is min-width: 1px it should take effect instead of the default, isn't it?

Comment: There's almost no point in having a media query targeting viewports greater than 1px - since that's all viewports. Just use `.text {font-size: 16px;}`, there's no need for a media query in that case. Maybe we need to revisit what you're trying to do? You want the font-size to increase in size as the viewport gets larger, correct?

Comment: For a start i just tried to use media query without real logic in it. But i can't make it work at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205654/discussion-between-brett-dewoody-and-oded-bartov).

Comment: Try this - https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/RwNMpLr. The default size is 16px. If your viewport is larger than 600px the font-size will be 100px.